# A matrix $B = A^8 - 11A^7-4A^6+A^5+A^4-11A^3-4A^2+A+I$ so what the $\det B$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

[image]

Ok. I really try to use the relation that since $A_{nxn}\quad$, $\det A^k = k^n \det A$

I can also use the $(a^3+b^3)$ and $(a^3-b^3)$ and stuck this expression seems is too much work for solve this problem.

$$[8^3-7^3-6\cdot 7^3 -4(7^3+6^3)+(5^3+4^3)+7\cdot 3^3+4(3^3-2^3)+1]\det A+1$$

Seems all the expression multiplier $\det A$ must be zero. But i suppose just the answer key.

Comment: Find the characteristic polynomial, $p(x)$, of $A$. This is, the determinant of $A-xI$. By [Cayley-Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem), $p(A)=0$. If $q(x)$ is that big polynomial such that $B=q(A)$, and you divide $q(x)=p(x)h(x)+r(x)$, then $B=q(A)=p(A)h(A)+r(A)=r(A)$. The advantage is that now the degree of $r$ is smaller than the degree of $p$. Since $p$ has degree $3$, then $r(x)$ will have degree at most $2$. So, you will have, at most to square $A$, to compute $r(A)$.

Comment: $\det A^k = (\det A)^k$ is the correct version of the identity you wrote. One way to proceed is to compute the characteristic polynomial of A, and then use the Cayley - Hamilton theorem to write $B = bA^2 + cA + dI$ for some real numbers $b,c,d$ and then just do the computation. Edit- too slow :)

Comment: sorry guys. i have been confused about the proprieties.totally. You right @RagibZaman and thank you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $A$ is a root of its characteristic polynomial. Such polynomial is
$$p_A(\lambda)=-\lambda^3+11\lambda^2+4\lambda-1\;,$$
so your matrix $B$ can be written as
$$B=-A^5p_A(A)-Ap_A(A)+I=I\;.$$ 
Therefore $\det B=1$.

---

How did I notice? Well, in general, one feasible strategy could have been the following: we calculate the eigenvalues $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, $\lambda_3$ of $A$ (which are all real as $A$ is symmetric) and then we get the eigenvalues of $B=q(A)$ by applying $q$, so $q(\lambda_1)$, $q(\lambda_2)$, $q(\lambda_3)$. The determinant of $D$ is then the product of these three quantities.

This is true because, if $A$ is similar to the matrix $D$ by means of a base change $M$, then $A^k$ is similar to $D^k$ by means of the same base change, so $q(A)$ is similar to $q(D)$, for every polynomial $q$ with real coefficients.

However, as soon as I computed the characteristic polynomial of $A$ (in order to get the eigenvalues), I immediately noticed that our polynomial $q$ could be written as $-x^5p_A(x)-xp_A(x)+1$.